# How can I play the cutscenes outside of the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the installation of the game there is a folder called `\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\Movies` which appears to contain all the cutscenes from the game in a file format `.bik`. Is there anyway to play these outside of the game, or at least without having to play the whole game up to that point to see them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To watch `.bik` files you need Bink Video player. You can get it [here](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkdown.htm)

As far as I can tell Mass Effect 3 have sound files in a separate file or there is something wrong with my setup.